# Carrousel Transform Rotate

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

How I can rotate a carrousel without the first image appears every time we click on "Next". I have the following code :

```
var image = 0;

$('.next').click(function(e) {

    image++;
    e.stopPropagation();

    $("#1").animate({  borderSpacing: -45*image }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY('+now+'deg)');
        $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotateY('+now+'deg)');
        $(this).css('transform','rotateY('+now+'deg)');
    },
        duration:'slow'
    },'linear');
});
```

I would like to have a carousel which simply switch to the next image when we click on "Next". You can find a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Elie76/va964ze4/).

Thanks

Comment: You need to keep the position of the current carousel item. Because you are using the wrapper div of the carousel items this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed little bit code into your existing **JS** and add one css property **transition** into your css.

Add CSS **transition: all 1s;** for increase or decrease rotation speed of carousel. I hope this snippet help you.

```js
 var image = 0;

 $('.next').click(function(e) {

  image++;
  e.stopPropagation();

  $("#1").animate({  borderSpacing: -45*image }, {
  step: function(now,fx) {
   $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotateY('+parseInt(-45*image)+'deg)');
   $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotateY('+parseInt(-45*image)+'deg)');
   $(this).css('transform','rotateY('+parseInt(-45*image)+'deg)');
  },
   duration:'slow'
  },'linear');
 });
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width:600px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px; /* Distance du carroussel */
  perspective: 700px; /* Distance du carroussel */
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
}

.carrousel{
  width: 200px; /* Centrer carroussel */
  height: 200px; /* Incliner le carrousel */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Placer la carrousel */
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s; /*Add this transition for increase or decrease rotattion speed*/
  
  /*-webkit-animation: Caroussel 10s infinite linear;  */

}

.plan{
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%; /* Hauteur de l'image */
  width: 150px; /* Largeur de l'image */
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 8em;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Caroussel{

  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}



.p1{
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
  transform: translateZ(200px)
}
.p2{
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p3{
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.p4{
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p5{
  background-color: purple;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p6{
  background-color: brown;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p7{
  background-color: grey;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p8{
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="1" class="carrousel">
    <figure>
      <div class="plan p1"></div>
      <div class="plan p2"></div>
      <div class="plan p3"></div>
      <div class="plan p4"></div>
      <div class="plan p5"></div>
      <div class="plan p6"></div>
      <div class="plan p7"></div>
      <div class="plan p8"></div>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <button class="next" style="margin-bottop: 10px">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Raeesh ! This is what I want too ;-)

Comment: I will test this carrousel on Safari and then if it works correctly, I come back to give you a big big thanks !

Comment: @Elie I have just added prefix webkit (Old Chrome and Safari Version) for css transition so now check this it will work on Safari also. I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

I have used CSS3 transition instead of jquery animate.
And then added css instead of calling `animate()`

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/va964ze4/5/

You can change transition effect and speed in CSS

```
transition: all 1s;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! This is what I want ;-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have added also **Previous** button with **Next** button.

```js
var image = 0;

// Click Previous button
$('.prev').click(function(e) {
 image--;
 e.stopPropagation();
 $("#1").css({
   "borderSpacing": -45*image,
   "transform": "rotateY("+parseInt(-45*image)+"deg)"
  });
});

// Click Next button
$('.next').click(function(e) {
 image++;
 e.stopPropagation();
 $("#1").css({
   "borderSpacing": -45*image,
   "transform": "rotateY("+parseInt(-45*image)+"deg)"
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 600px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px; /* Distance du carroussel */
  perspective: 800px; /* Distance du carroussel */
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
}

.carrousel{
  width: 200px; /* Centrer carroussel */
  height: 200px; /* Incliner le carrousel */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Placer la carrousel */
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.plan{
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%; /* Hauteur de l'image */
  width: 150px; /* Largeur de l'image */
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 8em;
  color:#FFF;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Caroussel{
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg)
  }
}



.p1{
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
  transform: translateZ(200px)
}
.p2{
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p3{
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.p4{
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p5{
  background-color: purple;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p6{
  background-color: brown;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p7{
  background-color: grey;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(200px)
}
.p8{
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(200px);
  transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(200px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="1" class="carrousel">
    <figure>
      <div class="plan p1">1</div>
      <div class="plan p2">2</div>
      <div class="plan p3">3</div>
      <div class="plan p4">4</div>
      <div class="plan p5">5</div>
      <div class="plan p6">6</div>
      <div class="plan p7">7</div>
      <div class="plan p8">8</div>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 50px; text-align: center;">
    <button type="button" class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is the solution for your problem?

**//HTML**

```
<div class="item a">A</div>

<div class="item b">B</div>

<div class="item c">C</div>

<div class="item d">D</div>

<div class="item e">E</div>

<div class="item f">F</div>
```

"Here the div class="next" Next "

"Here the div class="prev" Prev "

**//CSS**

body {

background: #333;

padding: 70px 0;

font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;

}

.container {

margin: 0 auto;

width: 250px;

height: 200px;

position: relative;

perspective: 1000px;

}

.carousel {

height: 100%;

width: 100%;

position: absolute;

transform-style: preserve-3d;

transition: transform 1s;

}

.item {

display: block;

position: absolute;

background: #000;

width: 250px;

height: 200px;

line-height: 200px;

font-size: 5em;

text-align: center;

color: #FFF;

opacity: 0.95;

border-radius: 10px;

}

.a {

transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #ed1c24;

}

.b {

transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #0072bc;

}

.c {

transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #39b54a;

}

.d {

transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #f26522;

}

.e {

transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #630460;

}

.f {

transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px);

background: #8c6239;

}

.next, .prev {

color: #444;

position: absolute;

top: 100px;

padding: 1em 2em;

cursor: pointer;

background: #CCC;

border-radius: 5px;

border-top: 1px solid #FFF;

box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;

transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;

}

.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }

.next:active, .prev:active {

top: 104px;

box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;

}

.next { right: 5em; }

.prev { left: 5em; }

**//JS**

var carousel = $(".carousel"),

```
currdeg  = 0;
```

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);

$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){

if(e.data.d=="n"){

```
currdeg = currdeg - 60;
```

}

if(e.data.d=="p"){

```
currdeg = currdeg + 60;
```

}

carousel.css({

```
"-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",

"-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",

"-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",

"transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
```

});

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer this [HTML + CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code formatting help centre and [edit] your answer format it.